# How to naming the Tab title with selected value with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I have used a Selectmenu to let user choose a value, and then I want to use this value to be the title of another tab's title.

Selectmenu is:

```
<form action="#">
<fieldset>
    <label for="Bit">Select a Food</label>
        <select name="food" id="food">
            <option>Cake</option>
            <option>Orange</option>
            <option selected="selected">Apple</option>
        </select>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Then in the tabs, I put code as below, but it doesn't work.

```
<div id="tabsa">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabsa-1">'$("#food").val()’</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Can you help?

Thanks!

Comment: User may change the value of that select box..? what you would do in that context..? do you need to bind the values of that select box wiht that anchor tag..?

Comment: Nope you need to execute your javascript code in a script block (along with adding dependencies - such as jquery etc.)

Comment: you can't use $("#food").val() inside html, it should be a script.

Answer (score 0):

Use change event to get the selected value

```
var catchDom= $("#tabsa li a");
catchDom.text($("#food option:selected").val());

$("#food").change(function () {
    catchDom.text(this.value);
})
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2u8cK/3/)

Comment: @TilwinJoy why..? :) :D

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="#">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="Bit">Select a Food</label>
            <select name="food" id="food" onChange="setValue();">
                <option>Cake</option>
                <option>Orange</option>
                <option selected="selected">Apple</option>
            </select>
    </fieldset>
    </form>

<div id="tabsa">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabsa-1"></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script>

function setValue() {
 $('#tabsa-1').html($('#tabsa-1').val());

}

</script>
```

(code not tested)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're trying to do something like this:

```
<script>    
   $(function() {
        $("#food").on("change", function(e) {
            $("#tabsa li").text($(this).val());
        });
    });
</script>

<!-- Rest of your markup -->
<form action="#">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="Bit">Select a Food</label>
        <select name="food" id="food">
            <option>Cake</option>
            <option>Orange</option>
            <option selected="selected">Apple</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
</form>
<div id="tabsa">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabsa-1"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is a little [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/H7v7J/1/) to demonstrate